# Getting data from cell above (Excel)

Tags: excel, formula

I am currently writing up an excel document to analyse the results of radon decay (physics).
For a particular section of the spreadsheet I need to get the data from the cell above and add 5 to it to give a value.
E.g say cell A1 had a value of 33901 A2 would have to equal 33906, A3 would equal 33911 e.t.c. I could enter the data manually but it gets very time consuming when I reach the larger data (seeing as I have hundreds of entries to work with). I need to be able to just copy paste a formula into the cells as I go and have it equal the right value.

I am familiar with the basics of working with formula in excel but no further than that.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **A2** enter:

```
=A1 + 5
```

and copy down if this is required.

**EDIT#1:**

An easy way to do this is to hi-light cells **A2** thru **A10** and touch <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>

Comment: When I try copying the formula through it just gives the values of A1+5 in each cell instead of the value of the cell directly above.